# Create delta zip to overlay previous install

Tags: git, gradle

## Background

We use Gradle at work to build our software (Java/C++/MATLAB), package per customer variations of configuration files and assemble a final aggregate installation of everything.

A part of the "customer variations" is a regular directory structure that has a set of copying/layering rules, so that we can share as much of the configuration between variations as appropriate.

We accomplish this today with a copyConfiguration task that looks something like the made-up repo **[I've recreated here](https://github.com/big-guy/gradle-copy-example)**.   Each variation is considered a separate subproject of the entire "config" project.  We copy in order (1, 2, project.name) with files in project.name overwriting identically named files from 1 or 2 (the same goes for 2 over 1).  We build a target directory and then zip it up for deployment. I've made up the names in the example, but consider that there are a dozen or so "component" subdirectories (aaa, bbb, etc) and 10-15 subprojects (with a maximum 'orderToCopy' length of around 5).  The file names aren't globally unique across the different components or subprojects (so you can't rely on fileA only existing under aaa/ or never under a different subproject's directory).

## Pain points

Every week, we re-install several variations based on which customers will be receiving the next release.  Right now, the install process is painfully manual and slow (usually overnight for a few hundred servers), so short of something catastrophic, we avoid re-rolling an entire release build of our configurations until the next install.  We make do by using a in-house "patch applier" system that lets us overlay changes without reinstalling everything.  These patches are built by hand based on what "needs" to be fixed.  This is sometimes painful when the same file is patched multiple times by different people or someone copies an identically named file into the wrong destination (e.g., we have multiple log4j.properties, but only one is correct in a given directory).

We also frequently have situations where one customer's variation (old-client) will need to communicate with another's newer variation (new-client).  This is usually handled by building a similar patch as above on top of the last delivered old-client configuration when we deliver new-client.  This is even more painful and stressful since these can sometimes build on top of one another and all of the patches are built by hand (e.g., copy this file here, rename this file, etc).   This used to be much worse before we had a VCS that supported branching...

## Problem/Desired goal?

I've been thinking about this off and on for several months, but I haven't found a good solution.  What I would like to be able to do is rely on information from the VCS (git, in our case) or some previous information (artifact, build area, etc) to construct a delta zip file for each variation from a given reference point.  In my example repo, if src/main/dist/aaa/2/fileA changed, in an ideal world, the delta patch zip would be empty for subproject1 and contain only the changed file for subproject2.

### Ideas

I've tried making a full build, downloading the previous build (based on a Gradle command line property), extracting it and then diffing the two output directories.  <del>I think I can make this work, but it seems dirty and works outside of Gradle.</del>  After pointing me to the delta-binary patches used by Mozilla, I found an [xdelta binary diff library for Java](https://github.com/alexkasko/delta-updater/) and made a proof of concept using it.

Any other ideas?  Is there a better declarative or idiomatic Gradle way of doing something like this?  If there's some way to rework the copyConfiguration to make this easier, I'm open to ideas.

### Abandoned Ideas

1. <del>I've been able to get a list of changed files using git whatchanged and then exclude()ing files that are not in my list in the eachFile{} closure.  This works as long as the "leaf" files are modified.  If src/main/dist/aaa/2/fileA changed, I would end up excluding aaa/1/fileA and aaa/subproject1/fileA and get the wrong contents for my patch build.  This also doesn't handle deletes where a file in 1 or 2 should now be used (because the file at the higher precedence has been deleted).  There's also a case of deleting all occurrences of a file such that we should install nothing, but I think that's an edge case that can be ignored for now.</del>  This seemed really hard to get right in all of the corner cases.
2. <del>I've also tried just taking the basename of all the changed files, but this over-selects common file names and makes the patch contain too much. e.g., if aaa/2/fileA changed, we'd end up building a patch for subproject1 that contained aaa/data/fileA and bbb/data/fileA (when no files is the "correct" answer).</del> I disliked this because the patch zip contained unchanged files and didn't handle deletes/moves.
3. <del>I've also thought about, but haven't tried yet, doing something similar to above.  Checkout to the previous commit, build, checkout to the commit to build the patch for and then hook into Gradle's incremental build feature.  We are still using Gradle 1.1, so that functionality isn't available yet for me.</del>  This was painful and required a script to exec Gradle twice.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I recall that Firefox uses incremental updates. Basically they ship an archive containing only changed and new files (and meta data about removed files), using binary-diffs where appropriate. The archives are generated by comparing two directories. http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/tools/update-packaging/ and https://wiki.mozilla.org/Software_Update:HowToManuallyGenerateMARFiles#Create_the_partial_mar

Comment: Just a thought - what about 'git bundle'?  It's designed to package up commits since some reference and let you apply them to another repo.

Comment: @nmaier Thanks, that gave me other keywords to search for.  I'll update the question with something new I've tried.

Comment: @randy-wandisco That doesn't work in my case, unfortunately, because the layout of the git directory doesn't match the final "installed" layout.  We layer many directories on top of one another to reuse common configurations between customers.  git bundle would keep the directory structure "as checked in" and not as "installed".

Comment: Link to [proof of concept for using delta-diff and Gradle](https://github.com/big-guy/gradle-copy-example/blob/master/patch.gradle)